Get borrow size of currency from Kucoin via Python
I want to get the current borrow size for the currency´s.
I tried that:
client = kucoin.Client(api_key, api_secret, api_passphrase)
response = client.get_accounts()

but the borrow size is missing in the response.
Do you have a proposals?
I could found that: https://www.kucoin.com/docs/rest/funding/funding-overview/get-account-detail-cross-margin
but I don´t know, how I can implement that in Python.
I tried that:
client = kucoin.Client(api_key, api_secret, api_passphrase)
response = client.get_accounts()


If you are following the advice on the page that your link refers, then you should get the correct details. If the correct details are not returned then you will need to ask Kucoin for help. There is nothing that you can change in your code to fix it.

your link shows url with /api/v3/margin/accounts - so maybe you could check source code for margin.py. I see the same url in get_margin_account_Detail()

Thanks:-) With "get_margin_account_Detail()" it works.

I tried also that:
import base64, hmac, hashlib, json, time

# constants
API_KEY = '***'
API_SECRET = '***'
API_PASSPHRASE = '***'

url = "https://api/v3/margin/accounts"

str_to_sign = 'GET' + '/api/v3/margin/accounts?quoteCurrency=BTC'

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(API_SECRET.encode(
    'utf-8'), str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())

passphrase = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(API_SECRET.encode(
    'utf-8'), API_PASSPHRASE.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())

headers = {
    "KC-API-SIGN": signature,
    "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": str(now),
    "KC-API-KEY": API_KEY,
    "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphrase,
    "KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

try:
    res = requests.get(
        url, headers=headers).json()

    print(res)

except Exception as err:
    print(err)

but it doesn´t work.

Since this is not an answer, could you please add this information to the original post?
